# Angular material table theming

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

I made a dark theme for my angular app but there is one problem. Everything changes color as expected but the material table headers color stays the same. What am I missing in the styling that it's not changing?

[image: light theme]

[image: dark theme]

how can I change the color of the header?

Comment: Did you work through the [theming guide](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/theming.md)? I think there is everything you need.

Comment: Can you go through this? https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: it should change, the text is changing also but the background doesn't and only on the header of the table, the other rows, buttons everything changes nicely